# Divide String REGEX

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression, regex-negation

I want to writre a Regular Expression to divide these two lines into rows

Example

1;John;Doe;45
2;jaja;dada;23

Result :

```
ID : 1 
Name : John 
Last name : Doe 
Age : 45
```

I used : (;)

This is what i did : https://regex101.com/r/By1Ei1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct, however it does not break the line when a space is encountered, so 45 and 2 appear on the same line, to fix this just add a space with `;` in square brackets. And use the `\n` subtitution like you did!

```
([; ])
```

[Run it here](https://regex101.com/r/By1Ei1/2)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer , i would like to know if i can add a text (Name , last name , age ) , https://regex101.com/r/By1Ei1/3

Comment: Why do you need to add text? Just store the different parts in named variables and use them as you like. Also, you should not use regex for adding `ID`, `Name`, etc. to the string.